# excel solver (Simplex LP) binary constraints

Tags: excel, binary, constraints, solver, simplex

I am solving an optimization problem.  the problem has binary constraints.  solver is (during iteration) setting those binary constraints to decimals between 0 and 1 (approximating a relaxed gradient search).  I wish to indicate to solver that it should just search over the discontinous values for 0..1.

Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, is there an algorithm in OpenSolver which does this, that mimics the simplex-lp, and provides a global optimum?

the cheap way to do it, is to right a for-loop, and iterate over the values.  I was wondering if there was a way to phrase it so that a nonlinear problem, becomes a linear problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Solver allows `bin` constraints. Make sure to select `Simplex LP` solver if your model is linear. Even though it is called Simplex LP it will actually solve MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) problems.

Comment: When it fails, it is often with partial values, indicating the binary constraint, is a constraint applied AFTER the gradient descent (values > 0, and < 1).  I am asking, is there a linear (MILP) solver that allows true boolean values i.e. ones that are discontinuously 0, or 1.

Comment: Gradient descent? That makes no sense to me. Make sure to select Simplex LP and not GRG Nonlinear. Also make sure to inspect the Answer Report carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The GRG Nonlinear and Simplex LP methods both use the Branch & Bound method when faced with integer constraints. This method "relaxes" the integer requirement first, finds a solution, then fixes one of the constraints to an integer and finds a new solution. [See the Solver on-line documentation](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-integer-programming).

It is a brute force search method and can take a considerable amount of time.

The Evolutionary method uses it's own algorithm for dealing with integer constraints and is typically much faster than the other two methods.

You ask about linearizing a non-linear problem - you would need to provide more specific information in order to answer that (e.g. What is your equation? How have you set up your solver problem? etc.)

Comment: "This method "relaxes" the integer requirement first, finds a solution"
....
Yes I know this.  I'm asking if there is an engine for solving MIP/Simplex problems with true binary constraints i.e. fields which can only take the value of 0 or 1, and ARE NOT relaxed during the iterative solution.

Comment: From [here](http://www.solver.com/mixed-integer-constraint-technology) it says, for Evolutionary method: "... integer variables and permutations are represented directly, and candidate solutions are generated that always satisfy integer and alldifferent constraints."